# Torsion free connection $\implies$ Jet coordinates $=$ Taylor expansion coefficients?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections, jets

Suppose we have some smooth n-dimensional manifold $M$ endowed with basis 1-forms $\theta^a$ with $a=1\cdots n$. Then $\theta^a$ are sections of the coframe bundle $F^* M$. In local coordinates ($x^a$ ) these are defined as $\theta^a = dx^a$ If we consider the 1-jets of $\theta^a$ such 1-jets $ j^1 \theta^a$ are then sections of the jet bundle $J^1 _n F^* M$.

In local coordinates the 1-jet prolongation is equivalent to a first order Taylor expansion around a point (lets choose $x_0$) $$j^{1}\theta^{a}(x)=\theta^{a}\mid_{x_{0}}+\frac{d\theta^{a}}{dx^{\alpha}}\mid_{x_{0}}\left(x^{\beta}-x_{0}^{\beta}\right)$$

The first term vanishes if we choose $x_0=0$ (the origin). Now a section of the 1- jet bundle over $F^* M$ is by definition a general connection $\Gamma$ on $F^{*}M$. Then we can write the above as:

$$\Gamma_{\alpha}^{a\beta}=\frac{d\theta^{a}}{dx^{\alpha}}\mid_{x_{0}}\left(x^{\beta}-x_{0}\right)$$

In a neighborhood of $x_{0}=0$, we have that $$x^{\beta}-x_{0}^{\beta}\rightarrow dx^{\beta}=\theta^{\beta}$$, and accordingly:

$$\Gamma_{\alpha}^{a\beta}=\frac{d\theta^{a}}{dx^{\alpha}}\mid_0 \theta^{\beta}$$

But this is clearly related to the compatible torsionless connection, which is defined (in slightly different notation) as: $$ d\theta^a= \Gamma^{ab} \theta_b$$. (**NOTE:** this really all looks cleaner if we write it in terms if moving frames or "frame fields")

So my question is:

Is the compatible torsion-free connection equivalent to a choice of coordinates on the jet bundle wherein the jet coordinatets match the coefficient of a taylor expansion?

Phenomenologically I would think of this as choosing coordinates on the jet bundle to be constants (the Taylor coefficients) such that their derivative vanishes (the compatible torsion free  *covariant* derivative). Does this make sense? If so can this be generalized to higher order jet bundles?

Comment: The purpose of jet bundles is to encode Taylor expansions. So I think provided you are careful about terminology you can erase the "torsion free connection" clause and the answer is yes.  What source are you using for jet bundles?

Comment: @RyanBudney    To match the frame bundle construction the source are local diffeomorphisms of open neighborhoods of $0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ to $M$ for the $\theta^a$ (since $FM$ is the bundle of such *invertible* 1-jets).  I thought a choice of vanishing covariant derivative of these 1-jets implies a particular choice of jet coordinates (i.e. local trivialization). Note: then $J^1 _n FM$ is really related to the *nonholonomic* bundle $J^1 _n J^1 _n M$

Comment: @RyanBudney  Since a choice of connection is equivalent to a splitting of the tangent space of the bundle, this makes sense intuitively (i.e. we have a particular subset of  local trivializations for a torsionfree condition), just not sure about formally?

Comment: I should probably note, if we're not at the origin then in a neighborhood of $x_0$ : $$\Gamma^{a \beta} _\alpha=\theta^a  \mid _{x_0} +\frac{d\theta^{a}}{dx^{\alpha}}\mid_{x_{0}} \theta^{\beta}$$  looks more like the *Cartan connection* which I'm not sure what to do with...